# An Arithmetic Encoding's length being ambiguous?

Tags: arithmetic, data-compression, encoding-scheme, communication-protocols

Say they are two tokens, A and B. A has probability weight 0.99 (and B has 0.01). If I want to encode the sequence "AAA", wouldn't the binary encoding just be "0"? And wouldn't that be the same for encoding "AA", or "AAAA", or an number of A's? How is the decoder supposed to know how many A's are sent when all it receives is the message "0"? Or is it absolutely necessary to have/add an EOF token? But in that case, the EOF token will have to be given some weight, which will detract from the weight of the other more meaningful tokens, right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you need to be able to indicate EOF (and EOF is obviously meaningful). Note that you may have a natural message boundary in terms of decoding; for example, if you are writing to a file then the file has a size and thus the information can be encoded in a trailer (e.g., how many of the final decoded characters should be discarded). If there's no natural boundary (e.g., this is one message of many in a stream), then you either need to prefix the message with the encoded length, or yes, reserve probabilities for the EOF token (note that you can adjust the probabilities to be dynamic in the number of characters previously decoded, if this makes sense).

Answer (score -1):

Arithmetic coding tries to get close to the theoretical maximum. Getting closer takes more effort. So two encoders will give different results, depending how much effort they put into the compression.

The easiest way to understand it properly is to write a decoder. It has to decode one A, two As, ..., thousand As, so each of these must be encoded in a different way. Once you have a decoder you can then write an encoder that produces something that will be decoded correctly. You have freedom in the encoder, not in the decoder.